# Twitter video upload fail on Android

Tags: android, video, twitter

I am trying to upload a video to twitter on Android.

Every time I use the API, I get a HTTP 400 (with no error message), on the APPEND command.

My request looks like this (using httpbin)

```
HEADERS

User-Agent: okhttp/3.2.0
Content-Length: 4000810
Total-Route-Time: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Cf-Ipcountry: JP
Connection: close
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="[Redacted]", oauth_nonce="[Redacted]", oauth_signature="[Redacted]%2BkY9kybcE%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1476240797", oauth_token="-[Redacted]", oauth_version="1.0"
Host: requestb.in
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=81302723-6d1b-4c0b-898a-ca52dd2aef10
Cf-Connecting-Ip: 118.238.220.243
X-Request-Id: e68c732e-5b59-4671-823a-f2ef1aa4e5c7
Via: 1.1 vegur
Cf-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"} => https for the real one
Connect-Time: 0
Cf-Ray: 2f0742ba47e0132f-NRT
RAW BODY

--81302723-6d1b-4c0b-898a-ca52dd2aef10
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="command"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 8

"APPEND"
--81302723-6d1b-4c0b-898a-ca52dd2aef10
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_id"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 20

"[REDACTED]"
--81302723-6d1b-4c0b-898a-ca52dd2aef10
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: video/avc
[Redacted binary gibberish]
```

The error I get while using the API is:

> Response 
>   {
>    protocol=h2, 
>    code=400, 
>    message=, 
>    url=https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json
>   }

The final file is 6mb; and `ffmpeg -i on the file yeild the result`

> Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: isommp42
>       creation_time   : 2016-10-12 02:21:19
>       com.android.version: 6.0   Duration: 00:00:22.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2387 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x480, 1135 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 25 fps, 25
>   tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2016-10-12 02:21:19
>         handler_name    : VideoHandle

The code to handle the upload looks like this:

```
class MPTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient {
    public MPTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession session) {
        super(session);
    }

    /**
     * Provide CustomService with defined endpoints
     */
    public VideoService getVideoService() {
        return getService(VideoService.class);
    }

}

// example users/show service endpoint
interface VideoService {


    @FormUrlEncoded()
    @POST("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
    Call<VideoUploadInit> uploadVideoInit(@Field("command") String command,
                                 @Field("total_bytes") String totalBytes,
                                 @Field("media_type") String mediaType);
    @Multipart
    @POST("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
    Call <VideoUploadPart>uploadVideoAppend(@Part("command") String command,
                           @Part("media_id") String mediaId,
                           @Part("media") RequestBody media, // The raw binary file content being uploaded. Cannot be used with media_data.
                           // Required after an INIT, an index number starting at zero indicating the order of the uploaded chunks.
                           // The chunk of the upload for a single media, from 0-999, inclusive.
                           // The first segment_index is 0, the second segment uploaded is 1, etc.
                           @Part("segment_index") String segmentIndex);

    @POST("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
      @FormUrlEncoded()
    Call<VideoUploadEnd>  uploadVideoFinalize(@Field("command") String command,
                             @Field("media_id") long mediaId);
    public class VideoUploadInit {

        @SerializedName("media_id")
        public final long mediaId;

        public VideoUploadInit(final long pMediaId) {
            mediaId = pMediaId;
        }

    }

    public class VideoUploadPart {

    }

    public class VideoUploadEnd {

    }
}
```

And the upload code:

```
 private void uploadChunk(final VideoService videoService, final byte data[], final long mediaId , final int fileSize, final int chunkPart) {
        final int maxChunk = 4 * 1000 * 1000;
        final int byteSent = chunkPart * maxChunk;
        final boolean isLast = byteSent + maxChunk >= fileSize;
        RequestBody body = new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return MediaType.parse("video/mp4");
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(final BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                sink.write(data, byteSent, isLast ? fileSize - byteSent : maxChunk);
            }
        };
        videoService.uploadVideoAppend("APPEND", String.valueOf(mediaId), body, String.valueOf(chunkPart)).enqueue(new Callback<VideoService.VideoUploadPart>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final Result result) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Uploaded video part");
                if (isLast) {
                    videoService.uploadVideoFinalize("FINALIZE", mediaId).enqueue(new Callback<VideoService.VideoUploadEnd>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(final Result<VideoService.VideoUploadEnd> result) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Finalized upload !");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(final TwitterException exception) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Failed upload finalization");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    uploadChunk(videoService, data, mediaId, fileSize, chunkPart + 1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(final TwitterException exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not upload video: " + exception);
            }
        });
    }


    private void tweet(TwitterSession pTwitterSession) {
        TwitterAuthToken authToken = pTwitterSession.getAuthToken();
        String token = authToken.token;
        String secret = authToken.secret;
        MPTwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = new MPTwitterApiClient(pTwitterSession);
        final VideoService videoService = twitterApiClient.getVideoService();
        final File videoFile = new File(AssetsUtils.getExportMoviePath(getApplicationContext()));
        Log.d(TAG, "File Size is " + (videoFile.length() / 1024 / 1024) + "mb");
        try {
            final byte data[] = Files.toByteArray(videoFile);
            videoService.uploadVideoInit("INIT", String.valueOf(videoFile.length()), "video/mp4").enqueue(new Callback<VideoService.VideoUploadInit>() { //XXX refactor this callback hell
                @Override
                public void success(final Result<VideoService.VideoUploadInit> result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Succeed INIT RESULT: " +result);
                    Log.d(TAG, "media ID is " + result.data.mediaId);
                    final long mediaId = result.data.mediaId;
                    final int fileSize = (int)videoFile.length();
                    uploadChunk(videoService, data, mediaId, fileSize, 0);
                    }
                @Override
                public void failure(final TwitterException exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed twitter init with " + exception);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException pE) {
            pE.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The media INIT call run successfully and return a media id. The append part fail on first chunk.

(Yes, it's all white because the content is still under NDA).

Comment: Here are twitter Error codes and explanations for developers. Maybe it will help you. 

https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes

  and this one  
  
https://dev.twitter.com/ads/basics/response-codes

Comment: @ArsenSench yeah I wish I could use it but the error message is blank. Updated the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out.

The request was not formatted as twitter wanted it.
I updated this code (you'd need a bit of refactor tho).

```
private void uploadChunk(final VideoService videoService, final byte data[], final long pMediaId , final int fileSize, final int chunkPart) {
    final int maxChunk = 4 * 1000 * 1000;
    final int byteSent = chunkPart * maxChunk;
    final boolean isLast = byteSent + maxChunk >= fileSize;
    RequestBody body = new RequestBody() {
        @Override
        public MediaType contentType() {
            return MediaType.parse(Encoder.MIME_TYPE);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTo(final BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            sink.write(data, byteSent, isLast ? fileSize - byteSent : maxChunk);
        }
    };
    final RequestBody mediaIdBody = new RequestBody() {
        @Override
        public MediaType contentType() {
            return MediaType.parse("text/plain");
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTo(final BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            sink.writeString(String.valueOf(pMediaId), Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
    };
    RequestBody appendCommand = new RequestBody() {
        @Override
        public MediaType contentType() {
            return MediaType.parse("text/plain");
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTo(final BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            sink.writeString("APPEND", Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
    };
    RequestBody chunkPartBody = new RequestBody() {
        @Override
        public MediaType contentType() {
            return MediaType.parse("text/plain");
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTo(final BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            sink.writeString(String.valueOf(chunkPart), Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
    };

    videoService.uploadVideoAppend(appendCommand, mediaIdBody, body, chunkPartBody).enqueue(new Callback<VideoService.VideoUploadPart>() {
        @Override
        public void success(final Result result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Uploaded video part");
            if (isLast) {
                videoService.uploadVideoFinalize("FINALIZE", pMediaId).enqueue(new Callback<VideoService.VideoUploadEnd>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(final Result<VideoService.VideoUploadEnd> result) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Finalized upload !");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(final TwitterException exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed upload finalization");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                uploadChunk(videoService, data, pMediaId, fileSize, chunkPart + 1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(final TwitterException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not upload video: " + exception);
        }
    });
}
```

And in the twitter api client:

```
@Multipart
@POST("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
Call <VideoUploadPart>uploadVideoAppend(@Part("command") RequestBody command,
                       @Part("media_id") RequestBody mediaId,
                       @Part("media") RequestBody media, // The raw binary file content being uploaded. Cannot be used with media_data.
                       // Required after an INIT, an index number starting at zero indicating the order of the uploaded chunks.
                       // The chunk of the upload for a single media, from 0-999, inclusive.
                       // The first segment_index is 0, the second segment uploaded is 1, etc.
                       @Part("segment_index") RequestBody segmentIndex);
```